# Uniform continuity implies finite number of downcrossings of Brownian Motion almost surely?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stopping-times

As mentioned in this [textbook by Morters and Peres](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Ealdous/205B/bmbook.pdf) on page 147:

> Note that $D(a, b, t)$ is almost surely finite by the uniform continuity of Brownian motion on the compact interval $[0, t]$.

where $D(a, b, t)$ denotes the number of downcrossings of the interval $[a, b]$ before time $t$.

How do I prove that this is true?

(Note: The above quote is edited since [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1308467/absolute-continuity-and-sample-paths-of-brownian-motion) mentions that the "absolute continuity" originally in the book is a typo and should be replaced with "uniform continuity")

Comment: Uniform continuity tells you that $|B_t(\omega) - B_s(\omega)| > \varepsilon$ implies that $|t-s| > \delta(\varepsilon)$ (where I supress the dependency of $\delta$ on $\omega$). By choosing $\varepsilon = (b-a)/2$ you can see that a downcrossing of a uniformly continuous path takes time at least $\delta(\frac{b-a}{2})$. So an upper bound on the number of downcrossings is $t \delta^{-1}$.

Comment: That makes sense. Would this also mean that, taking the limit as $a \to b$, the number of downcrossings diverges to infinity? Or would it still be possible to bound the number of downcrossings in this case?